# hibernate doesn't issue update after flush

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jta

I'm using hibernate 3.2.7 (same problem on 3.2.5) with spring 3.0.1, all deployed on weblogic 10.3 and with an Oracle 10g database. I'm using JTA transaction management and the transaction is distributed (it is actually started and ended in another application, this code is just in between).

The configuration used by hibernate is declared in my persistence.xml and is the following:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
<property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.WeblogicTransactionManagerLookup"/>
<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory"/>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="jta"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="auto"/>
```

The spring configuration regarding the transaction manager is the following:

```
<!-- Instructs Spring to perfrom declarative transaction managemenet on annotated classes -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>

<!-- Data about transact manager and session factory -->
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebLogicJtaTransactionManager">
  <property name="transactionManagerName" value="javax.transaction.TransactionManager"/> 
  <property name="defaultTimeout" value="${app.transaction.timeOut}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <!-- persistence unit is missing jta data source so that application server is not 
      creating EntitiyManagerFactory, spring will create its own LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean overriding data source-->
  <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
  <!-- specific properties like jpa provider and jpa provider properties are in persistance unit -->
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="my.persistence.unit"/>
</bean>


<!-- define data source in application server -->
<jee:jndi-lookup id="myDataSource" jndi-name="${db.jndiName}"/>
```

I'm using a generic CrudDao with an update method that looks like this:

```
public void update(Object entity) {
    //entityManager injected by @PersistenceContext
    entityManager.merge(entity);
    entityManager.flush();
}

public Object getById(Object id, Class entityClass) throws PersistenceException{
    return (Object)entityManager.find(entityClass, id);
}
```

UPDATED: added the getById method.

The code that does not work as expected looks like this:

```
MyObject myObj = getMyObjectThroughSomeOneToManyRelation(idOne, idOther);
// till now was null
myObj.setSomeDateAttr(someDate);
genericDao.update(myObj); 

MyObject myObjFromDB = genericDao.getById(myObj.getId(), MyObject.class);
```

The result is that if I print myObj.getSomeDateAttr() it returns me the value of someDate, if I print myObjFromDB.getSomeDateAttr() it still has null.

I've tried changing the update method to:

```
org.hibernate.Session s = (org.hibernate.Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
s.evict(entity);
s.update(entity);
s.flush();
```

And it still doesn't work.

When turning on the show_sql flag of hibernate I don't see any update occurring when doing flush nor when I query the entity manager for the object with the same id. The selects are all visible.
UPDATE:
At the end of the transaction the update is actually called and everything is written to the db. So my problem is "just" during the transaction.

I'm afraid the problem may be linked with the configuration of the transaction manager on spring and on hibernate.

Hope that someone can help me as I have already lost a day and a half with no luck.

Comment: If you post your getById method, I think we'll have clearer understanding of the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that the setSomeDateAttr method is implemented correctly.    The field you are assigning to is the one that is mapped to the db column.  Can you change some other attribute and try it out.  Are you sure you are not swallowing exceptions?

Comment: Yes and Yes. I'm sure the setSomeDateAttr is mapped to the right column. I'm sure I'm not swallowing exceptions (no try-catch whatsoever).

Comment: Is your crudDAO has single entitymanager? Update and getById has different entity manager or it is just typo?

Comment: In fact it was a typo. But anyway since it is injected with @persistencecontext it should always be the same instance. I think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the hibernate merge behaviour closely. As per documentation

- if there is a persistent instance with the same identifier currently
  associated with the session, copy the state of the given object onto
  the persistent instance
- if there is no persistent instance currently associated with the session, try to load it from the database, or create a new persistent instance
- the persistent instance is returned
- the given instance does not become associated with the session, it
  remains detached

As per your statement on the sql queries in log, it look like 
MyObject myObj = getMyObjectThroughSomeOneToManyRelation(idOne, idOther); returning the persistent object but when you modify it(becomes dirty) and call merge method, new state is copied to the current persistent object in session. If you see third point merge returns persistent object which is actually new manageable persistent object which you need to use in subsequent operations.

When you call find method hibernate returns the persistent object in session and not maneagable persistent object thats why you dont find the changes in object return by find.

To fix your problem change the reurn type of update method

```
public Object update(Object entity) { 
    //entityManager injected by @PersistenceContext 
    return  entityManager.merge(entity); 
}
```

and in service you need to use as below

```
MyObject myObj = getMyObjectThroughSomeOneToManyRelation(idOne, idOther); 
// till now was null 
myObj.setSomeDateAttr(someDate); 
//You can use myObj as well instead myNewObj
MyObject myNewObj= genericDao.update(myObj);  
 //No need to call get
//MyObject myObjFromDB = genericDao.getById(myObj.getId(), MyObject.class); 
System.out.println("Updated value:"+myNewObj.getSomeDateAttr());
```

Have a look at this [artical](http://techblog.bozho.net/?p=266) as well.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer but... The main problem remains why doesnt hibernate issue the updates when flush is called in the update method? I need the updates to be issued so the database can return the me the right values. This is all done in one (big) transaction so that state needs to be available.

Comment: As you are running in transaction. Within the transaction flush will not update the database but will maintain the state of the persistent objects in memory. it means if there is any detached entity it will try to load that entity from database. so in your work myObj is same as persistent object but not managable persistent object. If you see hashcodes for both of them, they will be different.

Comment: One more thing on Why it does not issue updates when you call flush? This is one of the reason of using transaction, it means unit of work. Spring will never updates to DB until current transaction is not completed.

Comment: The hashcodes are the same since I override the hashcode function and make it dependent on the id (i know not the best but it is like that). In the javadoc for session it says for the flush method "Flushing is the process of synchronizing the underlying persistent store with persistable state held in memory." As for persistence store I understand as being, in my case, the database.

Comment: Then you can see the memory addresses of both objects they will be different. About the javadoc, yes, thats what happening myObj is the persistent object(DB object) but myNewObj is called as manageable object which will be updated after transation completes. Hibernate keeps track of them separately so when you call another merge on myObj (try updating another field) you will get object state error but when you call merge on myNewObj (update another field) it will be succeeded.

Comment: I moved some of your comments to the answer and marked it as the right one. My problem was that the beginning of the method was not marked as '@Transactional' and therefore hibernate could never get me the right state of the changed object. After adding '@Transactional' everything works! Thank you for your help!